# How to make a transition effect using the transform origin?

Tags: html, css

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.fancy-link {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.fancy-link::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
}

.fancy-link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So... as you can see, The pseudo element is to come in from the left and leave towards the right, but if you run the code you'll see that it comes from the right and leave towards the right, Please i need the pseudo content to come in from the left and leave towards the right,I'm sure the transform origin property and attribute i used is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the transition you specified `all` but the only property you need to animate is `transform` (and not also `transform-origin`)

```css
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.fancy-link{
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
.fancy-link::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: 0.5s transform ease-in;
}
.fancy-link:hover::after{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancy-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```